# $V=A\oplus B\Rightarrow V^*=A^o\oplus B^o$ because $(V/W)^*\cong W^o$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Let $V/W$ be the quotient space. Then, we know that
$$(V/W)^*\cong W^o.$$
Where $^*$ denotes the dual space and $^o$ the annihilator.

In an [article of Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map#Quotient_spaces_and_annihilators), it is written that "as a particular consequence [of this], if $V$ is a direct sum of two subspaces $A$ and $B$, then $V^*$ is a direct sum of $A^o$ and $B^o$".

How can we make this deduction? I know how to prove that $V=A\oplus B\Rightarrow V^*=A^o\oplus B^o$ by using that $(A+B)^o=A^o\cap B^o$ (which is also trivial to prove), but how to use that $(V/W)^*\cong W^o$?